# Rails3 has_and_belongs_to_many - error on getting an attribute from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Given that I have following structure:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bs, :class_name => "B", :join_table => "ab"
end

class AB < ActiveRecord::Base
  #ab has a date column "creation_date"
  #ab also has a text column "creatior"
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I successfully retrieve "creation_date" attribute in `rails console`

```
console> A.find(1).bs.first.creation_date
        => "14/08/1874"
```

In controller

```
@a = A.find(1)
@bs = a.bs
```

But using it in a view (partial), I got following error

```
bs.each do |b|
  b.b_attribute #this is O.K.
  b.creation_date # cause error =>    undefined method `creation_date` for #<B:...>
end

 # also try to debug in partial
 A.find(1).bs.first.creation_date #=> this return data correctly
```

The problem as shown above, what can possibly cause `undefined method` whilst the direct attributes are still accessible.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

When you're dealing with an intermediate model, you shouldn't use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. That method works only when the join table is *not* a model. You need to make a clear distinction between the concepts of a **model** and a **table**. In rails, you rarely have access to the underlying table, most often you deal with the wrapping models.

If your join table has anything more than the foreign keys to `A` and `B`, and you need to access that additional data, then it needs to be a model. In your case, it is, but you're not using the correct relation. It should look like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abs
  has_many :bs, :through => :abs
end

class AB < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Afterwards, accessing `creation_date` and `creator` should be done through the `AB` model, since it really is an attribute that belongs to it.

Take a look here for a quick explanation with examples: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many